# The use of ext folder in websphere

Tags: websphere

Does anyone know what is the purpose of the lib/ext folder in WebSphere and what is the main difference between it and the shared library?

I am facing a lot of problems with WebSphere jars.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to know is that in case you use *the default classloading policy* **(Parent First)** in your WebSphere Server or in your application level, all classes included in jars inside **lib/ext** directory will definitely be loaded instead the same classes in your application (e.g. jars inside your WEB-INF/lib directory in a Web app).

Inside lib/ext there are usually non-standard libraries used by the WebSphere or you can also drop you own libraries so that they can be visible from every other class in the WebSphere (**CAUTION**: This sometimes can be a source of problems).

A more flexible way to set your own libraries in the WAS level is to use the **WebSphere [shared libraries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html)**.

The difference with lib/ext libraries is that you can more easily manage and set shared libraries in server or application level and not impose that every class in your server will use the lib/ext library.

Comment: I'm really sorry abouth this, but I downvoted your answer by a mistake. Now the answer must be edited before I can change my downvote to upvote. Could you make any changes to your answer?

Comment: @DmitriyKonovalov I've added some more info about the subject, if you are interested you can check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27103286/3701228

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between `WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext` and Shared library is that lib/ext libraries are included in **all** profiles and in **all** servers. They are also read by server extension class loader which is not configurable.

On the other hand shared libraries are configured in **specific** profile and can be associated with given server or specific application.

See following pages for more info:

- [WebSphere Classloaders](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_classload.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-5-0&lang=en)
- [Managing shared libraries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html?lang=en-us)

Comment: "lib/ext libraries are included in all profiles and in all servers." Thanks, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to alter/add to the content of ext/lib. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006159

Answer (score 0):

Holding global shared libraries (so only one global instance of those exists on the server, instead of the library being packaged in every single module).

Enjoy some detailed reading material on the bottom of this technote:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21322617